# Synchronization of SurfaceHolder's lockCanvas and unlockCanvasAndPost

Tags: java, android, multithreading, surfaceview, synchronized

I know that there are a lot of questions about this topic, however, I am still not completely satisfied with the answers provided.

**The situation:**
I implemented SurfaceView with drawing in another thread using SurfaceHolder like it is suggested in the developer's guide:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

**The problem:**
Sometimes I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Surface has already been released:

- when calling SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas()
- or when calling SufraceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost()

This means that my surface is sometimes released before I lock the canvas, and sometimes - between locking and unlocking it.

**My solution:**
I perform surface check and locking/unlocking canvas within synchronized blocks, so I know for sure that the surface can't get destroyed in between those actions. However, I have never worked with synchronized blocks and I wanted to ask if there is anything wrong with it. So far the code worked fine, but you never know when synchronization issues may show themselves, so I'm not completely convinced that this is the best way.

```
private class DrawingThread extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        while (!isInterrupted() && holder != null) {
            Canvas drawingCanvas = null;
            synchronized (this) {
                if (holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                    drawingCanvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                }
            }
            if (drawingCanvas != null && drawingCanvas.getWidth() > 0) {
                drawThisView(drawingCanvas);
                synchronized (this) {
                    if(holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(drawingCanvas);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if(drawingThread != null){
        drawingThread.interrupt();
    }
    drawingThread = new DrawingThread();
    drawingThread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    if(drawingThread.isInterrupted()){
        drawingThread = new DrawingThread();
        drawingThread.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    drawingThread.interrupt();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some hours of trials and errors I think I have figured it out. After all, all I had to do is to read the android reference. Here are some important things that I got wrong:

- `SurfaceHolder.getSurface.isValid()` only checks if the surface can
  be locked, so this check can (and does) fail for seeing is the canvas
  can be unlocked.
- To check if you can call `unlockCanvasAndPost()`,
  you just check if the `canvas` returned by `lockCanvas()` is not
  `null`.
- If the `canvas` is `null`, you should not unlock it (if you
  try it will throw an exception).
- If it's not null, you have to unlock it, otherwise your app will freeze if you activity tries to stop (after `onPause()` the `SurfaceHolder` tries to destroy the `Surface`, but since the `Canvas` is locked, it couldn't, so you get into a deadlock).

Hope this can help other "noobs". Finally, this is my final code for `SurfaceView`(the try/catch block is not necessary any more):

```
DrawingThread drawingThread;

private class DrawingThread extends Thread{
    public volatile boolean canDraw = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (canDraw) {
                Canvas drawingCanvas = null;
                if (canDraw && holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                    drawingCanvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                    if (drawingCanvas != null) {
                        drawThisView(drawingCanvas);
                        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(drawingCanvas);
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(IllegalStateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            canDraw = false;
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if(drawingThread != null){
        drawingThread.canDraw = false;
    }
    drawingThread = new DrawingThread();
    drawingThread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    if(!drawingThread.canDraw){
        drawingThread = new DrawingThread();
        drawingThread.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if(drawingThread != null) {
        drawingThread.canDraw = false;
    }
}
```

And thanks fadden for clarifying some points about drawing in another thread.

Comment: Your code don't unlock canvas if it is valid and have zero width. Why is that?

Comment: I guess the `getWidth() > 0` is actually not needed there, but the `canvas != null` is necessary, because in the `lockCanvas()` docs it says: "A null is returned if the surface has not been created or otherwise cannot be edited". So, if your surface is destroyed between `isValid()` and `lockCanvas()`, you will get `null` from `lockCanvas()`, in which case you should not unlock your canvas.

Comment: I will remove the condition `getWidth() > 0` now from my final code, just so people who need it will get the right version.

Comment: @IvanBatalov You never call `drawingThread.quit()` (i.e. in `surfaceDestroyed()`).

Answer (score 3):

The `synchronized` statement is used for mutually-exclusive access between multiple threads.  If you `synchronized (this)` in thread #1, then any other thread attempting to do the same will block until thread #1 exits the synchronized block.

If you only ever use it in one thread, it does nothing useful.  Of course, if you have multiple threads attempting to lock and unlock the Surface's Canvas, you should address the problem by not doing that in the first place, rather than trying to enforce exclusive access after the fact.

Your use of `interrupt()` and `isThreadInterrupted()` doesn't make a lot of sense.  If you want to raise a flag that tells a thread that it's time to stop running, a `volatile boolean` works just fine.  The only advantage of `interrupt()` is that it will wake the thread if it's waiting for an object to signal.  Further, consider the docs for the `isInterrupted()` call:

> Returns a boolean indicating whether the receiver has a **pending** interrupt request (true) or not ( false)

(Emphasis mine.)  Your code allows for situations like, "if the thread is alive, but an interrupt has been raised for it, go ahead and create a new thread while the old one is still running".

Some information about working with SurfaceView can be found in [this appendix](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity).  That links to an example in Grafika that starts and stops the thread based on the Surface callbacks, which you can find [here](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/HardwareScalerActivity.java).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I understand what you are saying. I will change the way I create/destroy threads, but I'd like to rephrase my main question: is it possible that between I call `holder.getSurface().isValid()` and `holder.lockCanvas()` in my drawing thread the surface is destroyed and how can I avoid it?

Comment: It's entirely possible for the Surface to go away, as you're running in a different thread and have not told the system that you're in the middle of using it. You don't avoid it. You check the return value from `lockCanvas()`, and don't try to draw if it's null. Once you've called `lockCanvas()` the system guarantees that the Surface won't go away until you unlock it.

Comment: That's what I thought and what I tried to do, but then sometimes I get these `IllegalStateException` (surface has been released) when trying to `lockCanvas()`. And even if the canvas is not null, it doesn't mean that the surface has to exist by the time I call unlockCanvasAndPost(). If the system just ignored my calls to lock/unlock the surface when it's destroyed, I'd be perfectly satisfied, but these exceptions mess everything up.

Comment: Having more than one renderer thread for a Surface is going to lead to unpleasantness. Again, the best place to fix that is by preventing the situation from happening, rather than adding synchronization to cope with it after it happens.

Comment: Thanks for keeping answering me. But I'm a bit confused. My `SurfaceView` is drawn in only one thread, no other threads do it. But the view itself is in a layout that is drawn in the UI thread. Thus, the surface is created/destroyed in the UI thread. And according to the developer's guide, this is how it should be done, unless I miss something (please look at the last 2 bullet points): [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue - drawing in SurfaceView using background thread and, sometimes, application hanged up when activity closed. Tracing revealed that surface in this case was destroyed between `lockCanvas` and `unlockCanvasAndPost`.

It seems the cause of such behavior was that I misinterpret docs a bit. `Callback.surfaceDestroyed` has to be used to hold surface from destroying (by not returning from it) until background thread finishes with surface.

```
DrawingThread drawingThread;
ReentrantLock paintLock = new ReentrantLock();

private class DrawingThread extends Thread{
    public volatile boolean canDraw = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (canDraw) {
                Canvas drawingCanvas = null;
                paintLock.lock();
                if (canDraw)) {
                    drawingCanvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                    if (drawingCanvas != null && drawingCanvas.getWidth() > 0) {
                        drawThisView(drawingCanvas);
                        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(drawingCanvas);
                    }
                }
                paintLock.unlock();
            }
        }catch(IllegalStateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            canDraw = false;
        }
    }
}

...

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    paintLock.lock();
    if(drawingThread != null) {
        drawingThread.canDraw = false;
    }
    paintLock.unlock();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing Lock, Draw and Unlock within a single synchronised statement fixed the Exception.

I came to know about the synchronised statement after reading this thread, correct me if this is a bad idea.

```
private class DrawingThread extends Thread{
@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();
    while (!isInterrupted() && holder != null) {
        Canvas drawingCanvas = null;
        synchronized (this) {
            if (holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                drawingCanvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            }

            if (drawingCanvas != null && drawingCanvas.getWidth() > 0) {
                drawThisView(drawingCanvas);
            }

            if(holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                 holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(drawingCanvas);
            }
        } // Lock -> Draw -> Unlock in a single synchronised statement

      }
   }
}
```